# Linux Debian - Empty a specific folder in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, debian

When entering data in my filesystem, some files got into the wrong directory and now I have to reset all of the folders with a specific name, without touching the files in the other folders of that subdirectory. Since all of the directories I want to empty **have the same name** I assume that this is possible, unfortunately I dont really know how to do that.

I have following structure:

```
dir

   subdir1

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty   

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt

   subdir2

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt 

   subdir3

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt
```

How can I empty **folder_I_want_to_empty** in every directory via the command prompt without deleting the folders or deleting any data from **folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [globbing](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```sh
cd dir
rm */folder_I_want_to_empty/*.txt
```

The first [asterisk](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF) matches all subdirs of the current folder and the second asterisk matches all files with `.txt` as file extension. You can further limit the matches by replacing the first asterisk with `subdir[1-3]`